# c# - Method Failing to Parse CSV File

Tags: c#, csv

I am trying to work through a school assignment that has us use a C# program to parse data from a CSV file and add it to a table in a local database. When I try to run the program though, the method I am using fails to parse any of the data into the object.

Here is the method I am using:

```
//Parse CSV line
    public bool ParseCSVline(string aLine) 
    {
        try
        {
            string[] fields = aLine.Split(',');
            this.Item_ID = int.Parse(fields[0]);
            this.Invent_id = int.Parse(fields[1]);
            this.Itemsize = fields[2];
            this.Color = fields[3];
            this.Curr_price = decimal.Parse(fields[4]);
            this.Qoh = int.Parse(fields[5]);
            return true;  //if everything parsed, return true
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write("Failed to Parse");
            return false;  //if a parse failed, return false
        }
```

When running the program the method keeps throwing the Exception instead of actually parsing the data. For clarity, here is the section in the Main program that is calling everything:

```
/Step 2 - Open input file
        //Set where the file comes from
        string filepath = @"C:\Users\Karlore\Documents\School\SAI-430\";
        string filename = @"NewInventory.csv";
        //Open reader
        StreamReader theFile = new StreamReader(filepath + filename);

        //Step 3 - Create an object to use
        Item theItem = new Item();

        //Step 4 - Loop through file and add to database
        while (theFile.Peek() >= 0)
        {
            //Get one line and parse it inside the object
            theItem.ParseCSVline(filename);

            //Check to see if item is already there
            if (theItem.IsInDatabase(connection))
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                //Add the new item to the database if it wasn’t already there
                theItem.AddRow(connection);
            }

        } //end of while loop
```

If anyone can point out where I may have made an error, or point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Comment: Your are passing the file name to the parsing function. You need to read a line of text from the file, and pass it.

Comment: To troubleshoot in future you can use your exception handling. I would use Console.Write("It broke " + ex.Message). I think ex.ToString() may give more info but I tend to start with the hint ☺

Comment: Thank you Cecilio. I will have to learn how to do that quickly. This class has thrown us into learning C# in a really weird way so obvious things like this aren't so obvious to me.

Comment: `theFile.ReadLine()` should get you started.

Comment: Dotnetperls has nice simple c# examples. Here is their csv reader http://www.dotnetperls.com/csv-file

Comment: Thank you once again Cecilio! Everyone else as well for the useful suggestions and resources.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line:

```
theItem.ParseCSVline(filename);
```

by:

```
theItem.ParseCSVline(theFile.ReadLine());
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped me get a much better understanding of what StreamReader can do.